# VBScript opening text file but it's showing up as empty

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, text, vbscript

I have a text file with some numbers, like so:

```
123456789
987654321
```

The file is called numbers.txt

I am trying to open the file and read it line by line and compare it another separate number

```
   'Create the file system object
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   identify = "123456789"
   WScript.Echo identify
   numfile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\numbers.txt", ForReading)

   WScript.Echo numfile.ReadLine
   WScript.Echo "test2"

   Do Until numfile.AtEndOfStream
      cell = numfile.ReadLine
      WScript.Echo cell
      If identify = cell Then 
         count = 1
      End If
   Loop

   WScript.Echo "end of loop"
```

However my code is getting stuck in an infinite loop with the AtEndOfStream loop. Furthermore,

```
WScript.Echo cell
```

is always an empty dialog box, and

```
WScript.Echo numfile.ReadLine
```

doesn't Echo anything, it just skips right to echo-ing "test 2". Where am I going wrong? The directory of the file is right, and it exists with the numbers

Edit: I tried

```
WScript.Echo numfile.ReadAll
```

and was just greeted with an empty dialog box

I also tried to open it as Unicode, but it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define ForReading:

```
Const ForReading = 1
```

, get rid of any "On Error Resume Next", and try again.

If you'd disabled the the evil OERN, you'd have seen an error message for

```
numfile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\numbers.txt", ForReading)
```

which should be

```
Set numfile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\numbers.txt", ForReading)
```

Comment: I have it defined, as well as all my variables, I just omitted from my pasted code. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks a ton! Such a simple answer, I can't believe I overlooked it.